# Find absolute path in shell script run by superuser for a path given by regular user. Resolve paths stored in variables to absolute paths portably

Tags: bash, shell

<sup>**Editor's note**: The OP's problem ultimately turned out to be *unrelated* to the fact that the script is run with `sudo` (as superuser), because `~` and `$HOME` by default still reflect the *real* user's home dir when running with `sudo` - unless you use `sudo -H`. This **question is at heart about how to resolve a *path stored in a variable* to an *absolute path* in a *portable manner***: by resolving `~` and `~<user>`-prefixed paths based on the current / specified user's home dir and, for relative paths, to an absolute path based on the *current* dir. The question's title was *later* amended to reflect that.</sup>

I have a regular user (non superuser) given path like:

**cfg.sh:**

```
 REL_PATH="~/mydir"
```

(It can contain absolute path, or path relative to the directory from where the main script is run, or path containing '~' for regular user homedir. And generally it can be any valid path for some regular user. Including any kind of tilde expansion).

I need to know the absolute path in the main script run by superuser:

**main.sh:**

```
#! /bin/sh

# Check if this script ran by superuser
if [ `id -u` -ne 0 ]; then
  printf "Error: This command requires administrative privileges!\n"
  exit 1
fi

# Save current directory and source the configuration
# from the directory relative to main.sh placement  
saved_path=$(pwd)
trap 'cd "$saved_path"; exit 1' 1 2 3 15
script_root_path=$(cd $(dirname $0) && pwd
cd "$script_root_path"
. ./cfg.sh
cd "$saved_path"

# Determine the regular user, that ran main.sh with administrative privileges
user=`who am i | awk '{print $1}'`

# Convert path given by user to absolute path (doesn't work)
ABS_PATH=`sudo -u $user readlink -f "$REL_PATH"`
# ABS_PATH=`sudo -u $user SLD=$REL_PATH sh -c 'cd $SLD; pwd'`

# Print absolute path
printf "$ABS_PATH\n"

# cd "$saved_path"
```

I tried different combinations with `sudo -u $user`. `cd` can't be used. `sh -c 'cd $REL_PATH'` is not working. The `dirname` and `basename` give the same relative path. The `readlink` prints an empty string...

I would like the solution to be portable.

I know readlink is not portable

I don't change the case of variables, because answers use this example. But it is better to avoid uppercase.

I source the configuration file as is in unsafe way, because the example with format checking would be very complicated.

**updated requirements:** The path given by a user is any valid path for that user, including:

- an absolute path
- a path relative to main.sh workdir
- a path with tilde syntaxes like ~ or ~/mydir or ~user2/mydir

For the absolute path:

- it doesn't matter if absolute path has inside .. or . like /home/user/dir1/../dir2
- really I need only ~ be expanded, the ~username syntaxes is valid and for regular user and for superuser

Comment: If you know the user name in `$user`, then the user's home directory can be found from `~$user`.

Comment: `REL_PATH` may be any path valid for user `$user`. It is not necessary to be started with ~. But I need the absolute path of couse

Comment: Yes. cfg.sh must be read like now. The current path must be stored

Comment: So in this context, what would `.` and `..` mean in `REL_PATH`?  Do they mean relative to the user's home directory, or relative to something else?  How can you know what `REL_PATH` is relative to?

Comment: @cdarke . and .. mean relative to the current directory. And this is the same directory for the superuser and $user (the directory the script is run). REL_PATH is realy any path valid for $user. (I solved the problem for my task. There are several solutions.)

Comment: The absolute path of the current directory can be obtained from `~+`

Comment: @cdarke: The `~+` is good to know, but it's not portable; `pwd` and `$PWD` are.

Comment: @mklement0 I'v updated the text. I use the "regular user" now

Comment: Thanks; (just realized that `who` calls it the "real user [name]"). However, at this point I think your question is unrelated to the superuser issue, because , at least by default, `~` still resolves to the _real_ user's home dir., not `root`'s. Your question is at heart about how to _manually_ expand a `~`-based path; see my updated answer.

Comment: Btw: You have a big security hole when you source a file that's modifiable by a normal user (the line `. ./cfg.sh`). That allows privilege escalation. Any process run as a user that can modify this file can leave any instructions in there and wait for your script to execute them as superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Note: The OP's problem is ultimately *unrelated* to the fact that the script is run with `sudo` (as superuser), because `~` and `$HOME` by default still reflect the *real* user's home dir when running with `sudo` - unless you use `sudo -H`.</sup>

- The primary problem is that the input path (stored in `$REL_PATH`) starts with a *literal* `~` (due to being part of a *double-quoted* string), whereas the shell only applies tilde expansion to *unquoted* `~` instances at the beginning of the word.
- However, the `~` *must* be quoted in `$REL_PATH` so as to *defer* expansion until the path should be determined in the context of the user running the script.

  - Note that the OP wants to support both `~` (current user's home dir.) and `~<username>` expansions (`<username>`'s home dir.)

It is therefore tempting to simply pass `$REL_PATH` to `eval` *as a whole*, but that is not only *risky*<sup>1</sup>, but is *likely to break* with paths containing shell metacharacters such as `&` and have leading or trailing whitespace or contain run of two or more spaces.

Therefore, the following, POSIX-compliant solution:

- isolates the `~` token at the beginning of a path and expands just *it*, using `eval` safely,
- then puts the path back together by appending the rest of the path to the expanded token.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Note: Assumes that:
#  * $REL_PATH is set to the input path.
#  * $user is set to the real username.

case $REL_PATH in
  \~|\~/*) # a ~ or ~/... path, expand the ~ based on the real user.
    # NOTE: If you know that `sudo` is never invoked with `-H`,
    #       you could simply use `$HOME` instead of `$(eval "echo ~$user")`.
    ABS_PATH="$(eval "echo ~$user")${REL_PATH#\~}"
    ;;
  \~*) # a ~<username> or ~<username>/... path; expand the ~<username> part.
    otherUserHomeDirRef=${REL_PATH%%/*}
    # Make sure that $otherUserHomeDirRef is a well-formed
    # ~/<username> token, so that `eval` can be safely applied.
    if ! expr "$otherUserHomeDirRef" : '~[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*$' >/dev/null; then
      echo "ERROR: Malformed input path: $REL_PATH" 1>&2
      exit 2
    fi
    otherUserHomeDir=$(eval echo "$otherUserHomeDirRef")
    if [ "$otherUserHomeDirRef" = "$REL_PATH" ]; then
      ABS_PATH=$otherUserHomeDir
    else
      ABS_PATH="$otherUserHomeDir/${REL_PATH#*/}"
    fi
    ;;
  /*) # already an absolute path, use as-is
    ABS_PATH=$REL_PATH
    ;;
  *) # a relative path, resolve based on *current* dir
    ABS_PATH="$PWD/$REL_PATH"
esac

# Print the absolute path.
printf '%s\n' "$ABS_PATH"
```

- Only POSIX-compliant parameter expansions are used.
- POSIX-utility `expr` is used for regex matching.
- Use of `eval` is safe here, because the input is either known to be safe or explicitly checked beforehand.
- The resulting absolute path is, per the OP's requirements:

  - *not* normalized; that is, components such as `.` and `..` are retained.
  - *not* checked for existence.

---

<sup>Note that it's generally not a good idea to use all-uppercase variable names such as `ABS_PATH`, because they can conflict with special shell and environment variables.</sup>

---

<sup>[1] Of course, the greater risk in the OP's script is the *sourcing of the config file*, which could contain *any* shell code.</sup>

Comment: It is very interesting and works with ~paths. But not with any kind of relative path

Comment: @РоманКоптев I've replaced the `readlink -f` with a POSIX-complian resolution to an absolute path.

Comment: Is it possible now just to use the second part and replace ~ to ~$user?

Comment: it has two problems now: 1) it works incorrect for `~name` and not just `~`. And this I can solve with `sed` with `^~$` and `^~/` templates. (May be it is not the best solution). 2) there are errors with non existing relative paths dipper than 1 directory/file like `aa/bb`

Comment: @РоманКоптев: The latest update should cover all cases. In the future, _please_ state _all_ your requirements _up front_, directly _in the question_. In your case, this would have meant: describe and give examples of all path forms that you want supported. Also, please take a look at how to create an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry. I realized those details when the script was working

Comment: And write updated requirements in your question (with a clear header `updated requirements`) and not in the comment of one of the answers. Easier to find for new readers.

Comment: It's something wrong. It returns /current_dir//rel_path for some relative path rel_path to me for example

Comment: @mklement0 Look the updated requirements, especially two last points. They do the things simpler

Comment: @РоманКоптев: I've updated my answer again, including a more robust way to determine `$script_root_dir`. The way you do that in your question is currently broken, so perhaps that's where the `/current_dir//rel_path` problem comes from. My code works fine in this case with `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`.

Comment: @mklement0 I don't need relative path to be relative to `script_root_path`, but to working directory just `pwd` or `saved_path`. The code is looking ok, but... Real problem here is: my shell (Ubuntu /bin/sh) does not understand `[^/]*)` like "everething started with something but not with /". It understands this like "if it starts with ^ or /". It will print paths ^dir or /dir like /path_to_script/^dir and /path_to_script//dir. And a relative paths remains as they are. The paths of type ~name remain as they are too.

Comment: Understood re working dir - answer updated. Also, I've removed the `[^...]` constructs - try again, it should work now. The curious thing is that I did test against `dash`, which is what `/bin/sh` is on Ubuntu, but I tested on OS X and must have used a more recent version. The POSIX spec. actually calls for `!` rather than `^` as the negation char., and that _does_ work on Ubuntu (verified on 12.04).

Comment: @mklement0 I can print the home dir just using `$(echo ~)` or $(echo ~uname). Is it really needed to use `eval`?

Comment: Re just `~`: If you're not worried about someone invoking your script with `sudo`'s `-H` option, then, yes, you can use `$(echo ~)`, or, preferably, simply `$HOME` (this is also stated in the code comments above).
By contrast, you _must_ use `eval` to evaluate `~$user`.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to use `realpath`.

for Ubuntu/Debian:

```
$ sudo apt-get install realpath
$ cd /tmp && touch a
$ realpath a
/tmp/a
```

for Mac:

```
$ cd /tmp && touch a
$ realpath a
/private/tmp/a
```

Comment: If you have to install something first, the solution is by definition not portable.
Also, your question doesn't address how to resolve `~` in the context of the _real_ username while running as superuser.